# VueJS, Display form fields in separate rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, tailwind-css

In my vue component I have a form, there I'm trying to add two fields with labels

```
<div class="bg-certstyle-background-light " slot="modal_content">
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <div class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-4 border-b space-x-2">
                        <!-- Team member -->
                            <dashboard-input-label class="col-sm-2 mb-2 w-full" identifier="first_name">
                                {{ 'Team member' }}
                            </dashboard-input-label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 mb-6 w-full">   
                                    <input 
                                        name="first_name" 
                                        type="text"
                                        class="form-input w-full relative z-10"
                                        placeholder="Search user"
                                    >
                            </div>    
                        <!-- Team member -->
                    </div> 
                    <div class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-4 border-b space-x-2">
                        <!-- Schedule name -->
                            <dashboard-input-label class="col-sm-2 mb-2 w-full" identifier="schedule_name">
                                {{ 'Schedule name' }}
                            </dashboard-input-label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 mb-6 w-full">   
                                    <input 
                                        name="schedule_name" 
                                        type="text"
                                        class="form-input w-full relative z-10"
                                        placeholder="Schedule name"
                                    >
                            </div>    
                        <!-- Schedule namer -->
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is what I've tried so far, But the problem is, this gives me following output,

[image]

Instead of this way, I want to add the second label and field in a new row...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a outer div-container with a `flex-direction: row` with two div-container with `flex-direction: column` inside, which represent your label and field.

Or this bootstrap example could fit: "[Two Columns With Two Nested Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)"

Example:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:green;">One</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">Three</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">Four</div>
  </div>
<div class="col">
```

Another alternativ could be a css-grid.

Some nice tips for [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)